# Resize BorderPane according to resolution

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a BorderPane(also VBox and Rectangle) which I would like to resize according to screen size. I use my application on 14" and 21" monitor. Is there any way to resize the components according to screen size?

Answer (score 1):

I hope, that I understood you right:

```
    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

    //let the window use the left half screen:
    stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth() / 2);
    stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setStyle("-fx-fill: red;");

    vBox.getChildren().add(rect);

    //not necessary, because always max size (root element of the scene):
    //vBox.minWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
    //vBox.minHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());

    rect.widthProperty().bind(vBox.widthProperty());
    rect.heightProperty().bind(vBox.heightProperty().divide(3));

    stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));

    stage.show();
```

If you resize the Window, then the Elements will automatically resize them itself.

Comment: Is there any way to do this by using the parent element size?

Comment: It's alredy done with the parent element size. rect is a child of vBox, and rect binds to the vBox size.